# Deal with Google Play updates in my app

Tags: android, database, google-play

How do you deal with updates of an Android app as a developer?

In particular, (1) if i have changed the database scheme in the update, how can i be notified when the app is about to get updated?

even more specifically, (2) is there one entry point i can put code that deals with updates and be done with it? or do i must check for the database version each time i try to access it?

Comment: Have a look at SQLiteOpenHelper's methods... especially onUpgrade()... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, [SQliteOpenHelper#onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) is the method you're looking for. From documentation:

> Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

This method is available starting from the API 1, so it'll work for all devices your application can be installed on.

**Upd:** whenever you create the instance of SQliteOpenHelper, you pass the database version into its constructor (take a look at constructors in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)). So, when you make a first version of your app, you pass, for example, `1` as the version number. This number is saved in the database file. Later on, when you make a new version of application **and** you need to make some changes in the database schema, you change this version to `2`. During the construction `SQliteOpenHelper` sees that the version stored in db file is `1`, `2` the version passed into the constructor is `2` - so it invokes `onUpgrade()` method where you write the code which will change the schema accordingly.

Comment: How would this method know if my database needs to be updated or not? does old version and new version represent the google code of my apk?